# Create Table SQLite 3 Error

Tags: sqlite, create-table

Could some please explain why I am getting an error when creating this table below?

```
   CREATE TABLE Login
    (
      Username TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      Password NOT NULL,
      LastUpdate DEFAULT DATE('now', 'local'),
      Status TEXT,
      CustomerID INTERGER,
      CHECK (Status='active' or Status='inactive')
    );
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error: near "(": syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) shows that the expression for the default value must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
LastUpdate  DEFAULT (DATE('now', 'local')),
```